Why does CPython implement GIL and V8 does not?
I'm seeking insights about CPython's decision to utilize the GIL compared to V8, the JavaScript engine or others that don’t.
While I understand that no language can excel in all aspects, I'm intrigued by the performance considerations, particularly in server-side and API-related tasks.
I'm interested in comparing its advantages and disadvantages to other dynamic languages’ implementations. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Hi! Your question is asking for opinions, which isn't allowed on this site. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

@Ars_Codicis maybe I wrote it not precisely but my intention is to understand technical difference between implementations and why do they work this way. Could you edit my question to ask about facts not opinions.

@Ars_Codicis correct me if I am wrong but statements like: “Gil is got at this, this and that. But weak at…”, “Jit is working this way so it allows to do this and that but is problematic to handle xyz” are the answers to my question and they are technical facts not opinions

I don't know much about Python, but I do know V8, so I can give this a shot from that perspective.
My understanding is that a GIL ("global interpreter lock", for those unfamiliar with the term) is primarily an easy and robust (=not bug-prone) way to implement an interpreter for a language with multi-threading features, and it might even have performance benefits when you assume that in practice there won't be very many threads anyway. But once you have a GIL, it impedes scaling to many cores, and it's very hard to get rid of it. So, in Python's early days its developers made a decision that relying on the GIL was "good enough for now", and nowadays they are struggling to get rid of it. You can read a lot more detail about the motivations and challenges at PEP 703.
V8's situation is quite different, so it's a bit difficult to make a direct comparison. Contrary to Python, JavaScript is single-threaded, so V8 has never had to deal with the language concurrency issues that a GIL helps to solve. V8 does use some amount of threading internally (mostly for GC and compilers), but all of that has been designed to not rely on a GIL (but instead to avoid locking whenever possible, and use fine-grained locks where locking is necessary). Even now that JavaScript and WebAssembly are looking into adding multi-threading features, the responsible developers are well aware of how unfortunate a GIL is for scaling, so the specifications won't assume that there is one, and the engines (V8 and others) won't implement one.
FWIW, using a GIL or not is pretty much unrelated to whether your language is dynamic or not, and also unrelated to whether your engine uses jitting or not.

I was more interested in the history of the language implementations and the trade-offs of those implementations. On purpose, I asked about dynamic languages because I do not see a point of comparing, e.g., Python with GIL to some not GC static language with GIL. I was aware of PEP 703 which is a hint that GIL is problematic. Thank you for giving a shot to my hated question...

Is it that different? Python is only executed in a single thread, native bindings might run multi threaded. JavaScript runs only in a single thread (one active execution context per agent), native calls (fetch et.al.) might run in multiple threads. Job queues and mutex signaling is also pretty similar

And for real multithreading one needs multiple processes in python and multiple agents (webworkers, …) in JS and messaging for communication (except that JS has SABs, not sure if python has a similar concept)

@JonasWilms Python has https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html, JS has nothing equivalent. The fact that effectively only a single Python thread is executed at a time is an unfortunate consequence of CPython having decided to use a GIL internally -- an "ideal" Python engine wouldn't make that choice, and would hence offer real multithreading with threads, not force you to use multiple processes as a workaround. But, sure, you could say that CPython crippling its multithreading implementation and JS not having the concept at all is kind of a similar end result for the time being...
